# Transient VO Iterator not returning correct index

Tags: oracle-adf

I have a main page as "main.jsff" in a Taskflow, lets say "A" where I am showing a list of clickable urls stored in a Transient VO named as "TransVO" via a LOV component. This Transient VO is getting populated in an external TaskFlow, lets say "B" which is dragged and dropped as a region in the main.jsff .

In "TransVO", attributes are set as Passivated and in TaskFlow - B, I have a bean class with backingbean scope where I am populating TransVO with my logic.

The content of LOV is getting displayed properly via the TransVO but when I click on any link of the above list then the control is entering into the external taskflow "B" and always returning me the first row of "TransVO" which should not happen since I need to redirect to proper URL base on selected row.

Any suggestion on how I can resolve this issue while using the TaskFlow as region concept?

Comment: Which JDev version you are using? Show us the code you use to populate the VO.

Comment: Did you set the Key Attribute in your VO?